# How to update Existing Server Name used on View (SQL Server 2014) using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

There is a **Supply Management System** that has been assigned to me, I have to study that for the customization request of the client. I have been searching for a while to find a  possible solutions for my scenario. But still no luck, however I got a back up plan to do so.

Here's the details(My new PC):

**My local SQL Server Name** : DEV01\SQLExpress 
**Database** : S_Premium -      The database of the **supply management system**
               GeoBos         - This is dedicated for another system,                       I restored it for testing purposes to my local SQL Server Name.

**S_Premium** and **GeoBos** is dedicated to a different systems but the data being used is Integrated with each other.

**Scenario:**

I have been moved to another PC with another SQL Server.
The **S_Premium** is using 50+ Views and Stored procedures which some of their queries is integrated to the servername of **GeoBos**(Example Above).

**S_Premium Views query example:**

SELECT DISTINCT ..... FROM  **LnkdSrvrBOSS**.GEOBOS.BOS.T_OBR_Hdr

LnkdSrvrBOSS - came from GeoBos previous server name 
GeoBos - database name 
BOS.T_OBR_Hdr - is a table under database "GeoBos"

---

What I did is deleting the **LnkdSrvrBOSS** manualy for every Views/Stored Procedures(It worked), But my problem is I have to do it manually for all Views and stored procedures that causing me a long time process.

**Question:**

1.) Is there a query that can replace or update the "LnkdSrvrBOSS" of "SELECT DISTINCT ..... FROM  **LnkdSrvrBOSS**.GEOBOS.BOS.T_OBR_Hdr" from Views/Stored Procedure ? 
 
2.) Do I really have to delete the "LnkdSrvrBOSS" manually(One by one)? 
 
3.) Or should I create a another SQL Server name "LnkdSrvrBOSS" and restore the database in there?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Linked-Server with the same Name on your local-machine